# ¿Cómo realizar un planteamiento problemático en PSeInt?

Tags: pseint

He venido avanzado un poco sobre el uso de PSeInt, observando sobre las [matrices de este código](http://algoritmosurgentes.com/algoritmo-complejo-en-pseudocodigo-pseint/multiplicacion-de-matrices?fbclid=IwAR2eWP3DJpdZDbJi5u_tXMp85P7HHvHP9pBlbFlcAogikQrmNM3si2H9tHk).

Pero aún no logro entender por completo todas sus funciones, su estructura básica fácilmente comprendida:

```
Algoritmo sin_titulo
  Definer myvariable Como Entero;

  myvariable<-10;

  Escribir myvariable;

FinAlgoritmo
```

He venido analizando muy cuidadosamente esté [código](http://algoritmosurgentes.com/algoritmo-complejo-en-pseudocodigo-pseint/multiplicacion-de-matrices?fbclid=IwAR2eWP3DJpdZDbJi5u_tXMp85P7HHvHP9pBlbFlcAogikQrmNM3si2H9tHk) para poder plantear y obtener el resultado de un problema.

Pueden explicarme como realizar un planteamiento problemático el cuál describe

***Se tiene una matriz de 15 filas y 12 columnas. Realice un algoritmo que permita
leer el arreglo y que calcule y presente los resultados siguientes:***

- El menor elemento de la matriz
- La suma de los elementos de las cinco primeras filas de la matriz.
- El total de elementos negativos que se encuentran entre la quita y novena
  columna.
- El número de elementos primos que se identifiquen en toda la matriz.

Y así al final poder realizar un análisis del problema, encontrar las: entradas, procesos y salidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que esta respuesta llegue a tiempo.

> Se tiene una matriz de 15 filas y 12 columnas. Realice un algoritmo que permita leer el arreglo y que calcule y presente los resultados siguientes:
>
> - El menor elemento de la matriz
> - La suma de los elementos de las cinco primeras filas de la matriz.
> - El total de elementos negativos que se encuentran entre la quita y
>   novena columna.
> - El número de elementos primos que se identifiquen en toda la matriz.

Dado este problema, lo más recomendado para que tu algoritmo sea comprensible y organizado sería la organización de cada uno de los siguientes problemas en "Funciones" o "Subprocesos".
Dentro de cada uno de los subprocesos, la forma de realizar cada uno de los problemas, se resuelve mediante el uso de 2 ciclos Para, para recorrer entre las filas y columnas de la matriz de tu arreglo, y el uso de contadores y/o acumuladores.
Ten en cuenta que los ciclos de iteración, así como su función en el algoritmo, serán distintos en cada problema, por lo que no pueden combinarse.

Por ejemplo, el primer problema, hace un recorrido por la matriz entera, almacenando en un acumulador el valor que considere el menor, esto puede realizarse con un...

```
Si (elemento_de_matriz_a_evaluar) < (elemento_actual_en_acumulador) Entonces 
      elemento_actual_en_acumulador <- elemento_de_matriz_a_evaluar;
FinSi
```

Mientras tanto, el segundo problema solo pide que busque en las primeras filas de la matriz, teniendo en cuenta que los arreglos empiezan en 0 (excepto en modo Flexible y Personalizado) y tomando en cuenta que tu arreglo se compone de 15 filas y 12 columnas, por lo que su dimensión es [15,12], se tomaría el recorrido de filas de 0 a 4, en lugar de 0 a 14 como se haría en el ejercicio anterior, de igual manera, en el problema 3, se toman las columnas entre la quinta y novena (4 a 8 en el arreglo), de entre todas las columnas, esto es un poco más difícil de visualizar, pero quedaría de tal manera...

```
Para i<-0 Hasta 14 Hacer
   Para j<-4 Hasta 8 Hacer
      //instrucciones
   FinPara
FinPara
```

Ya que usualmente en matrices, para la matriz [ i , j ], el primer ciclo o ciclo exterior recorre las filas (0 a 14) y el segundo las columnas (0 a 11).

El último problema no supone ningún problema, ya que solo se evalúa cada elemento de la matriz, y en caso de cumplir la condición de ser primo, se recurre a sumar una unidad al acumulador, para de esta forma, lograr que cuente cada vez que encuentra un primo.

```
Si (condiciones_de_primo_se_cumplen) Entonces
   cont_numero_primo <- cont_numero_primo + 1;
FinSi
```

Espero que esta respuesta te haya ayudado. Que tengas un buen día :)